# Android official alphabet fast scroll view

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollbar, fastscroll

[image: Android alphabet fast scroll view]
Is there an Android official alphabet fast scroll view? If yes, how to use it?

And I find some third party lib like [MaterialScrollBar](https://github.com/turing-tech/MaterialScrollBar), but I prefer official version if it exists.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You can see this in android contact app also. If you explore the contact app source code you can find out here is the contact app code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/android-6.0.0_r11/src/com/android/contacts

Comment: @DynamicMind Yes, It has used in many Android system pages which contain a list of data such as Notifications page. This is very useful in some situation, and I am confused how Android don't provide official version view.

Answer (score 0):

What a pity, there is no such thing untill now. However, there are some useful classes such as:AlphabetIndexer in case you want to implement yourself from official components like NestedScrollView, RecyclerView

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html

Comment: Yes, I've found AlphabetIndexer class. But Android seems hasn't provided official component that I asked.